# Can I write an Automator/AppleScript script to download all the iTunes app updates?

Tags: itunes, applescript, automator

This is related to [How can I tell iTunes to always download free updates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/how-can-i-tell-itunes-to-always-download-free-updates)

I would like to write a script to tell iTunes to download all the free app updates available, and have that script run regularly using iCal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this feature is currently not available or easy to implement. There has been mention that the next version of iOS and iTunes may include this feature. But its all speculative until it is actually released.

Comment: I'll second that. Unless iTunes provides an option, I don't see a stable way to accomplish this. Even with Automator/AppleScript/Keyboard Maestro etc., there are just too many things to consider: No apps may be available for updates, apps may be age-restricted (and therefore need an additional click), store may be unavailable, app may be unavailable; leading to an additional dialog box to handle for each event. Yucks!

Comment: This should be less of an issue when iOS 5 and iCloud come into play--assuming you are using newer devices that can support iOS 5 and iCloud. These will be rolled out on October 12, 2011.